# Git windows installer skip choosing install location

Tags: git

I found a tutorial to install Git.

[image]

In the tutorial, I should be allowed to choose the Git installation directory after the first step, but I was not allowed to choose, and I didn't care. The installation directory selection should be as shown below:

[image]

An error will be reported at the end of the installation. I have repeated it many times but cannot solve it.

**The drive or UNC share you selected does not exist or is notaccessible. Please select another.**

Answer (score 3):

After a few tries, I found out that we can use Git-2.43.0-64-bit.exe /DIR="E:\Git" to select file path for us.